# android dev for playstore

Tags: android, encryption

I have 2 questions regarding android Play Store.

1. I am developing an app that sends data(email,password) from an android app to my database(mysql) using json. Currently I am not using any encryption between. 
   Does Google Play Store check this? Must the data be encrypted in order to be accepted into the playstore? I read that its a must for amazon so I am curious.
2. When I publish my app to the playstore, will it be there forever? Even if I don't come out with updates?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about #1...
 #2 There is a setting in the developer site where you uncheck the App is Published.  If you uncheck this it will no longer be published to the playstore.